# How to get accurate line of code of Android Webview error: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: bla

Tags: android, webview

This error doesn't happened on Desktop Browser,
how to get more accurate line of code that error for that kind of error on `Android WebView`?

```
error: I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <", source: bla --> bla is main website
```

Which line of the html that causes that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote debuggng can show the error https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/webviews

For my current case, the problem is because the ajax request didn't intercepted (so the cookie was not set). On my webapp/server returns html text when the user not logged in (since the cookie is empty) and that result evaluated by jquery as json, so it would show `Unexpected token <`.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, you can't get to know what which line in the webpage is problem. U can only display Console.log from webpage javascript.

If u can, try to debug with Console.log: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/debugging.html

Remember to enable javascript in WebView
`webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`